# Is it possible to use filter within mutate?

Tags: r, dplyr

In my example below, I'm trying to do a mutate that does a rank within filtered criteria.  My end goal is to filter, but keep the full data frame.  I simply want my ranks to be done based on the filtered criteria.  My `df_goal` below gets me the correct ranks, but would require me to then use a `left_join` to add them to the original `df` which seems like a waste.  Is there a solution within `dplyr` that would allow me to rank the original `df` with the `filter` criteria?  I was thinking that perhaps a pipe within a `mutate` would work, but I had no success.

Example:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble::tribble(
        ~slugSeason,         ~namePlayer, ~groupPosition, ~slugPosition, ~ptsPerGame, ~astPerGame,
          "2019-20",      "Aaron Gordon",            "F",          "PF",        11.3,           3,
          "2019-20",     "Aaron Holiday",            "G",          "PG",           3,         1.8,
          "2019-20",       "Abdel Nader",            "F",          "SF",           3,         0.3,
          "2019-20", "Admiral Schofield",            "F",          "SF",         4.4,         0.2,
          "2019-20",   "Al-Farouq Aminu",            "F",          "PF",         4.2,           1,
          "2019-20",        "Al Horford",            "F",          "PF",        18.8,         4.2,
          "2019-20",        "Alec Burks",            "G",          "SG",         8.5,         1.8,
          "2019-20",       "Alex Caruso",            "G",          "SG",         3.2,         1.6,
          "2019-20",          "Alex Len",            "C",           "C",         4.2,         1.6,
          "2019-20",  "Alfonzo McKinnie",            "F",          "SF",           0,           0
        )

df <- df %>% 
  group_by(groupPosition) %>%
  mutate(ptsRankbyPosition = rank(desc(ptsPerGame))) %>%
  ungroup() 

df_goal <- df %>% 
  group_by(groupPosition) %>%
  mutate(ptsRankbyPosition = rank(desc(ptsPerGame))) %>%
  ungroup() %>% 
  filter(slugPosition %in% c("PG", "SG", "SF") & ptsRankbyPosition > 1 |
           slugPosition == "C" & ptsRankbyPosition > 1) %>% 
  mutate(addlRank = rank(desc(ptsPerGame)))
Created on 2019-11-05 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not clear about your expected output.  `filter` removes the rows/keep the rows

Comment: Look at `mutate_if`

Comment: I want to be able to use the filters to create the rank column.  I simply want to be able to use the filters on the original df and rank without losing the rows that get removed with a traditional filter.

Comment: If you are creating a column, then use `replace` i.e. `mutate(addlRank = NA_real_, addlRank = replace(addlRank, slugPosition %in% c("PG", "SG", "SF") & ptsRankbyPosition > 1 |
           slugPosition == "C" & ptsRankbyPosition > 1, rank(desc(ptsPerGame[slugPosition %in% c("PG", "SG", "SF") & ptsRankbyPosition > 1 |
           slugPosition == "C" & ptsRankbyPosition > 1])))`

Comment: Thanks.  Is there a cleaner way of doing it without having to restate the filter again in the vector after rank?

Comment: You can create an index column and reference that in the `replace` i.e. `mutate(index = slugPosition %in% c("PG", "SG", "SF") & ptsRankbyPosition > 1 | slugPosition == "C" & ptsRankbyPosition > 1, addlRank = NA_real_, addlRank = replace(addlRank, index, rank(desc(ptsPerGame[index])))) %>% select(-index)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is using `replace` after creating a logical column

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
 group_by(groupPosition) %>%
 mutate(ptsRankbyPosition = rank(desc(ptsPerGame))) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 mutate(index = slugPosition %in% c("PG", "SG", "SF") & 
           ptsRankbyPosition > 1 | 
          slugPosition == "C" & ptsRankbyPosition > 1,
        addlRank = NA_real_, 
        addlRank = replace(addlRank, index, rank(desc(ptsPerGame[index])))) %>%
 select(-index)
# A tibble: 10 x 8
#   slugSeason namePlayer        groupPosition slugPosition ptsPerGame astPerGame ptsRankbyPosition addlRank
#   <chr>      <chr>             <chr>         <chr>             <dbl>      <dbl>             <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1 2019-20    Aaron Gordon      F             PF                 11.3        3                   2     NA  
# 2 2019-20    Aaron Holiday     G             PG                  3          1.8                 3      3.5
# 3 2019-20    Abdel Nader       F             SF                  3          0.3                 5      3.5
# 4 2019-20    Admiral Schofield F             SF                  4.4        0.2                 3      1  
# 5 2019-20    Al-Farouq Aminu   F             PF                  4.2        1                   4     NA  
# 6 2019-20    Al Horford        F             PF                 18.8        4.2                 1     NA  
# 7 2019-20    Alec Burks        G             SG                  8.5        1.8                 1     NA  
# 8 2019-20    Alex Caruso       G             SG                  3.2        1.6                 2      2  
# 9 2019-20    Alex Len          C             C                   4.2        1.6                 1     NA  
#10 2019-20    Alfonzo McKinnie  F             SF                  0          0                   6      5
```